# Where is my user's home folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts

Recently I installed Ubuntu and Wine.

I can't see all folders in Ubuntu and tried to navigate to

```
/home/username/.wine/drive_c/windows/profiles/All Users/Application Data/
```

I couldn't find the `/home/username/` folder. At the time of installation, I think I encrypted it.

Is there a way to get out of this? Only the `public` folder is visible under `/home`.

Answer (score 23):

In Ubuntu (and other linuxes), your 'home' folder (generally know as `$HOME`) exists at the path `/home/<your-username>/`, and will, by default, contain a collection of folders, including one called Public.

If you open the [file manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_%28file_manager%29) at `$HOME`, then it will open in this folder.
Once there, if you press Ctrl+L, you should find that the full location that you're currently viewing is shown in the location bar.

From a terminal, you can also enter `echo $HOME` to find out the path.

It's also worth noting that on Linux, files/folders that start with a '.' are considered hidden, and so the `.wine` folder won't appear in the file manager's listing unless you show hidden files.
You can do this by pressing Ctrl+H, or from the View menu > Show Hidden Files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the Windows C:\ structure at `/mnt/c/` in the Bash environment.

Therefore, my Documents folder is at `/mnt/c/Users/Ben/Documents/.`

or Alternatively, for updated versions of windows, Hold down Shift while right-clicking in your desired Windows directory
Select "Open Linux shell here"